# sumif two columns with same value then calculating total score

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12GTfRsdYE7ClCuBahdqZiSyzfV44pUoA9fhmQJw9dL0/edit?usp=sharing

my aim is to calculate total score of multiple choices Question.
1)-if the ANS=INPUT then it return PT column value 2, o.w. zero.
2)-based on the score in step 1. sum the total scores.

i use the formula
=SUMIF(B2:B11*(C2:C11=D2:D11))
but not the correct ans 10.

What can i do to fix the formulat. thx in advance

Comment: `=SUM(FILTER(B2:B11,(C2:C11=D2:D11)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=sumif(index(eq(C2:C11,D2:D11)),true,B2:B11)
```

***OR***

```js
=sumproduct(eq(C2:C11,D2:D11),B2:B11)
```

[image]